# Declaration of Arrays in Sub Procedure

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I can not figure out what problems with those codes are?

It keeps producing:

> IndexOutOfRangeException

```vb
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Please input the length of the array")
    Dim n As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim numbers(n - 1) As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Please inform us the number you want to find")
    Dim x As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        Console.WriteLine("Please input the {0} number", i)
        numbers(i) = Console.ReadLine()
    Next
    examining(x, n, numbers(n - 1))
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

    Sub examining(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal n As Integer, ByVal ParamArray      numbers() As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        If numbers(i) = x Then
            Console.WriteLine("There exists {0} in the array", x)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If i = n - 1 Then Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist in the array", x)

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the exception stack trace, so we can see which line is causing the problem.

Comment: I don't know this language but shouldn't it be `examining(x, n, numbers)`, not `examining(x, n, numbers(n - 1))`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply way to check of an array contains something:

```
If numbers.Contains(x) Then
 'it does
Else
 'it does not
End If
```